# Insert partial/component at dynamic location

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I created a blog where I've got a `{{downloads}}` component showing the downloads which belong to a post.
Currently I render the downloads below `{{{post.content}}}`.

I'd like to have a special string withing `post.content` like [postDownloads] and render `{{downloads}}` there.

**Is this somehow possible or are there other approaches to solve this problem?**

I put together an easy example illustrating one of the use-cases I'm trying to solve: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/raresalihu/3/edit

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      title: "cool post title", 
      content: "<p>Lorem ipsum</p>[postDownloads]<p>coool stuff</p>",
      downloads: [ { src: "http://example.com/cool-stuff.zip", name: "cool stuff"},
                   { src: "http://example.com/cooler-stuff.zip", name: "cooler stuff"}]};
    }
  }
);
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h2>My Blog example</h2>
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/down-loads">
  <h3>Downloads</h3>
  {{#each download in downloads}}
    <p><a {{bind-attr href=download.src}}>{{download.name}}</a></p>
  {{/each}} 
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{#with model as post}}
    <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
    <div>{{{post.content}}}</div>
    {{down-loads downloads=post.downloads}}
  {{/with}}
</script>
```

Comment: There's no way to break up your content on the server? Create a beforePostDownloadsContent and a afterPostDownloadsContent? Really, I think you shouldn't be sending random HTML from the server to the client anyway.

Comment: I parse my Markdown on the server instead of having to do it everytime on the client.
I can put in the downloads easily on the server but my problem(s) are much more complex. The download I try to insert here is just an example but it could be any component.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render handlebars template programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215620/render-handlebars-template-programmatically)

Comment: +1 to what @Gaurav said. If you know at which point you insert the dynamic outlet, then it should be easy for you to split the data on the server. I would strongly recommend avoiding what you're seeking to do as it could easily open up security vulnerabilities since it seems you're dealing with content generated by users.

Comment: When I split it by the server I can't use the Ember goodness anymore in the frontend and have to subscribe to DOM events instead. It's a blog without user generated content (comments are handled by Disqus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like in an ideal world you'd be able to get a more structured representation, but if you're confident you can unambiguously find the placeholder (and you trust it to be in a reasonable place), you could split the HTML in half at that point and render the two halves of the HTML on either side of your injected content.

You could extract that process pretty easily into a component; take a look at [this JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ratatedowo/1/edit?html,js,output) for an example. Using the component there, in your sample above you could do something like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{#with model as post}}
    <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
    {{#replace-sigil body=post.content sigil='[postDownloads]'}}
      {{down-loads downloads=post.downloads}}
    {{/replace-sigil}}
  {{/with}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would summarize your requirements as so:

1) Provide a single string with the post content.
2) Within that content include handlebars helpers that will be processed to generate embedded content.

The easiest way to do this is to process the original post content as a handlebars template on the server.  Use the handlebars compiler on the server to produce a final HTML string that you send to the client as the post content.

If you also need the handlebars helpers to access the context of the template/controller on the client, then you will have to do some the handlebars compiler on the client and process the post text on the client with the proper context from the post.  You could do this with a custom helper.

In the client case you could use the HTMLBars compiler and runtime within Ember to better integrate with Ember, rather than handlebars.

If your downloads content is static (meaning it is just HTML), then you can always use {{{downloads}}} to include the html in the output.  I am assuming you want full HTMLBars or handlebars syntax in the downloads content.